# Finding rank of a matrix depending on parameters p

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Hi i having a trouble with calculate rank of matrix.
Matrix is:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        5 &p & 5 & p  \\
        1&1& 1& 1\\
        p&p & 2& 2\\
        \end{matrix}
$$
So far i get:

1)From first column substract 2nd column:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        5-p &p & 5 & p  \\
        0&1& 1& 1\\
        0&p & 2& 2\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

2)From 3rd row substract 1st row:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        5-p &p & 5 & p  \\
        0&1& 1& 1\\
        -5+p&0 & -3& 2-p\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

What now i have to look at my paremeter p or what?

Comment: Try swapping the first and second row and then subtracting appropriate multiples of it from the second and third row. You should be able to work out the possible ranks of the matrix easily after thatn.

Comment: @amd i should do i after 2nd point or should i start again with initial matrix?

Comment: I meant starting from the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Interchange first and second rows and reduce:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
5&p&5&p\\
p&p&2&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-5R_1,\,R_3-pR_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&p-5&0&p-5\\
0&0&2-p&2-p\end{pmatrix}$$

So if $\;p=2,\,5\;$ the rank is $\;2\;$, otherwise it is $\;3\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1. R1 $\iff $ R2
2. In the new matrix replace R2 by R2-5R1  why?
3. In the new matrix replace R3 by R3-pR1   why?

Discuss the result.